# Which entity types need Controllers generated for Web API OData Entity Framework solution?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I Have an Model First Entity Framework project.  It contains Enums, Complex Types, and 1:1 relationships with inherited types.

Example:  I have a Coupon type.  A coupon has either a single FixedOff or PercentOff entity (inherited from a base of ValueOffBase).

Question:  Do I need to add a controller to the abstract base class?  Or just each of the concreate descendent classes?

I also have a EF complex type called DateRange which has a Start and Stop date.  Do I add controllers for that too?

Comment: You may run in to using `[ResponseType(typeof(ValueOffBase))]` (which should allow you to return both). Then you'll probbaly need to decorate with `[KnownType(typeof(FixedOff))]` & `[KnownType(typeof(PercentOff))]` so the serializer knows what's coming.

Comment: Brad, thanks.  Sounds reasonable, but I am still wondering if I should point the Add Controller to the base class, each of the child classes, or some combination thereof.  I'm 'guessing' from your reply that I would add a controller to the base class and then decorate it with these attributes?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to add an ODataController, I think you needn't to add controller for abstract base class. As a fact, OData controller follows up the name convention as:

```
public class {EntitySetName}Controller : ODataController
{
...
}
```

Same as DateRange.

I suggest you can use the Attribute Routing. Then you can use any class name to create the controller. [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) is the introduction of attribute routing.

Comment: Thanks! Looking into this.